# A critique of TeX?

Tags: tex-core, programming, books

Is there any informative critique of TeX along one or all the lines below:

- TeX, the typesetting engine (including its algorithms)
- TeX, the typesetting language
- TeX, the programming language
- TeX, the program

(I'm not looking for a discussion of these features here; I'm looking for published references.)

Comment: While the answers so far are nice, most of them are from the "TeX community". Are there any papers in serious CS journals etc.?

Comment: Worth to be added could be “TeX, the markup”. I mean, distinguishing content and presentation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've just found this paper, which seems to address some of the issues I want:

> [25 Years of TeX and Metafont: Looking back and looking forward — TUG 2003 keynote address](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/beebe-2003keynote.pdf) by Nelson Beebe [*TUGboat* 25:1, 2004]

Abstract:

> TeX has lasted longer than many other computer software technologies.
>
> This article reviews some of the history of TeX and METAFONT, how they
>   have come to be used in practice, and what their impact has been on
>   document markup, the Internet, and publishing.
>
> TeX has several design deficiencies that limit its use and its
>   audience. We look at what TeX did right, and with 25 years of
>   hindsight, what it did wrong.
>
> We close with some observations about the challenges ahead for
>   electronic representation of documents.

Are there any other published references?

Answer (score 24):

> [*E-TeX: Guidelines for Future TeX Extensions*](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-3/tb29mitt.pdf) by [Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach)  [*TUGboat* 11:3, 1990]

Abstract:

> With the announcement of TeX 3.0, Don Knuth acknowledged the need of
>   the (ever growing) TeX community for an even better system. But at the
>   same time, he made it clear, that he will not get involved in any
>   further enhancements that would change *The TeXbook*.
>
> TeX started out originally as a system designed to typeset its
>   author's own publications. In the meantime it serves hundreds of
>   thousands of users. Now it is time, after ten years' experience, to
>   step back and consider whether or not TeX 3.0 is an adequate answer to
>   the typesetting requirements of the nineties.
>
> Output produced by TeX has higher standards than output generated
>   automatically by most other typesetting systems. Therefore, in this
>   paper we will focus on the quality standards set by typographers for
>   hand-typeset documents and ask to what extent they are achieved by
>   TeX. Limitations of TeX's algorithms are analyzed; and missing
>   features as well as new concepts are outlined.

Answer (score 19):

> [LuaTeX: Howling to the moon](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-2/hagen.pdf) by Hans Hagen, (Tugboat, 26:2, 2005)

Not really a critique of TeX the program, but explains some reasoning that went behind luaTeX--the future of TeX.

Abstract:

> Occasionally we reach the boundaries of TeX and programming then becomes
>   rather cumbersome. This is partly due to the limitations of the typesetting
>   engine, but more important is that a macro language is not always best suited
>   for the task at hand.

Answer (score 17):

> [Don’t take LaTeX files from strangers](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/tex-login.pdf) by Checkoway, Shacham, Rescorla (2011)

Critique of TeX's sandboxing, and how it is a possible attack vector.

Abstract:

> TeX, LaTeX, and BibTeX files are a common method of collaboration for
>   computer science professionals. It is widely assumed by users that
>   LaTeX files are safe; that is, that no signicant harm can come of
>   running LaTeX on an arbitrary computer. Unfortunately, this is not the
>   case: In this article we describe how to exploit LaTeX to build a
>   virus that spreads between documents on the MiKTeX distribution on
>   Windows XP as well as how to use malicious documents to steal data
>   from web-based LaTeX previewer services.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found this critique of TeX80, an earlier version of TeX:

> [Observations on TeX from a divergent viewpoint: Introduction and Memo to STI staff](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb04-2/tb08letters.pdf) by J.R. Rouser [*TUGboat* 4:2, 1983]

It also contains comments and responses by Don Knuth, David Fuchs, Michael Spivak, Richard Palais, and Barbara Beeton.